# Pulp MILP issue , conditional constraints , condition based on known parameters

Tags: linear-programming, pulp

I am seeking advice on incorporating conditional constraints in linear programming models using pre-defined parameters. Specifically, I need to create a constraint for fuel purchases at gas stations based on pump rates. The condition is that if the pump rate is zero, then the fuel purchased should also be zero. The pump rate is a known parameter, and the variable 'x' represents the fuel purchased.

Here is my current approach:

```
    if (pump_rate[i] <= 0):
            x[i].setInitialValue(0)
            x[i].lowBound = 0
            x[i].upBound = 0
    else:      
         lp_prob += x[i] <= pump_rate[i] * time_at_pump[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't tinker with the variable properties....  just constrain it to zero if the condition is true:

```
if (pump_rate[i] <= 0):
     lp_prob += x[i] == 0
else:      
     lp_prob += x[i] <= pump_rate[i] * time_at_pump[i]
```